# Problems with IEnumerator WaitForSeconds in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, ienumerator

So Im trying to destroy enemies in a while loop, waiting 1 second in between (can they make waiting a bit harder??) Problem is, all enemies are getting destroyed at the same time, theyre not waiting for WaitForSEconds. 
In my while loop I call each enemy by their tag, which goes from Enemy1 to Enemy5.
Heres my code.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherObject)
{


    int i=1;
    while (i<=numenemies)
    {
        string tag="Enemy"+i;
        destroyenemy=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag);
        Destroy(destroyenemy);
        i++;
        StartCoroutine(DestroyWait ());


    }   
 }
 IEnumerator DestroyWait()
 {
   Debug.Log ("so far...");
   yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
   Debug.Log ("so good");

 }
```

In my console from my debug log, Im getting 4 "so far..."  and then 4 "so good". its not waiting for 1 sec then outputing so good.

Ive been reading up on this and man its so hard to just pause the script for 1 second! what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no , It will stop game

Answer (score 2):

Move all your code inside a coroutine:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherObject)
{
    StartCoroutine(DestroyAllEnemies());
}

IEnumerator DestroyAllEnemies()
{
    for(int i = 1; i<=numenemies;i++)
    {
        string tag="Enemy"+i;
        destroyenemy=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(tag);
        Destroy(destroyenemy);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
 }
```